# Why Measurement Models versus Interactions?

Tags: interaction, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, measurement

I am trying to understand the difference between a model where a latent variable is regressed on some outcome versus an interaction of the measures of the latent variable being regress on the same outcome.

Factor analysis assumes we have a latent factor X that produces several measures Z. We can factor analyze a set of variables and calculate or estimate each person's score on on the latent X. We can jointly model this in a structural equation model or a Bayesian framework. Either way, we regress a latent variable on an outcome.

How is this different from estimating a model where you include the base terms and multiplicative interactions of all of the measures of the latent variable in the model? Can't we back out the effect of a person's score on the latent variable by using their observed responses on the measures and predicting their outcomes using the fitted interaction model?

Comment: I'm not sure how the interactions are relevant to latent variable model - all effects are additive, not multiplicative in the sem.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I am trying to understand why Y = a + W + X + W*X is different from Y = a + Z where Z is a factor analyzed X and W.

Comment: Rereading, I'm confused by your terminology. You say we regress the latent on the outcome. But isn't it an outcome not a predictor (we regress Y on X). Perhaps write out your models in whatever your favorite SEM code is (or draw a diagram, but that's more difficult).